# Search, Create and Move in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, html-parsing

I have a directory of about 800 html files.  I am trying to search each file and return text between tags.  Then I want to create a directory with that text and move (or copy) the files there.  This seemed like a pretty easy endeavor when I thought it up but I am having a ton of problems even identifying the modules I would need for this.  I have looked at File::Find and glob, but am not exactly sure about how I would implement this with a regex for txt within the files (not the file name.)  I am basically a newbie to perl so any and all help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT
To clarify:  What I am trying to accomplish:

Read Directory = ~/me/project/

For ~/me/project/ find all the files =~ /.html$/i

For each file, search the html for =  div class="recip" id="objectTo">(.*) /div

For every (.*) IE john@doewww.com or John Doe create a directory with that same name

Loop back and move every file that has an instance of xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com or John Doe to its corresponding directory.

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: How should the code determine the names of the moved or copied files?

Comment: via a scalar.  my initial thought was that i could write a regex saying something like $html =~ m{<span>(.*)</span} . The match would return a piece of text which would be something like "From John Doe".  Then a folder would be created named "From John Doe".  Then all the files that matched that From line would be moved there.  So maybe it would actually be an array?  I have 800 files with about 180 unique "From" values that I am trying to capture.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide *brief* examples of the HTML you'd like to use in determining moved or copied filenames. How should the code fish out the "From" values? Remember, we are completely unfamiliar with your problem and require specific information to give you useful suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with File::Find.

You will create a 'wanted()' function, and within that function, the name of the file found will be `$File::Find::name`. You can then use that to open a file handle, read in the file, search for the tags and extract the data that you're looking for, and close the file handle. File::Find will then move on to the next file.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

sub wanted {
    my $file=$File::Find::name;

    # if the file has the extension '.html' (case insensitive) ...
    if( $file =~ /\.html$/i ) {
        my $FH;
        open( $FH, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' for reading: $!";
        local $/ = '';
        my $contents = <$FH>; # slurp file into $contents
        # search $contents for the tags that you're looking for,
        # 
        close $FH;
    }
}

my @directories = (
      './htmlfiles'
    , './www'
    , './web'
);

find(\&wanted,  @directories);
```

Warning: The code passes `perl -c`, but I haven't run it.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question, Check out [HTML::Strip](http://search.cpan.org/~kilinrax/HTML-Strip-1.06/Strip.pm) for stripping HTML markup from text.

Comment: [HTML::Restrict](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Restrict) can also be used to remove the markup.

Comment: Who said anything about stripping? The comment attached to the question reads like [rar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1316130/rar) rather wants to selectively grab some text at a certain place in the DOM, for which [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web::Query) and [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://p3rl.org/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) are suitable. This is rather difficult once the mark-up is gone.

Comment: thanks for clarifying daxim.  that is exactly right.  i want the html files intact and don't think i need to remove the markup as long as my regex is onpoint for what i am matching.  i am using the tags to identify the text i want to use as the directory names that will be created.